# How to wrap the element with matching button text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to `append` the `div` to the `button` with the corresponding to that `button text`

(i.e. In the case of below example the `button text` is `"Download"` so i am appending the `div class` as `new` and if the `button text` is `"Upload"`
i will `append` some other `div class`).

And for the `appending div` I am using [wrap API](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn" title="run">Download</button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var buttontext = $("button").text();
      alert(buttontext);
      $('button[text="Download"]').wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to get the `button text` like this `button[text="Download"]` but it is not working.

Finally i want the output something like this

```html
<div class="new">
  <button class="btn" title="run">Download</button>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could user jquery's `contains` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button:contains("Download")').wrap("<div class='new'></div>");
});
```

Here is a working codepen:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/MJpwdz

And the documentation on `contains`:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains